# Salesforce GACK when uploading Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, gack

This [post from nearly three years ago](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) says that Stack Exchanging is a viable option for troubleshooting gacks. Clicking the Upload button on a managed package is throwing the following GACK:

`Error ID: 745113341-129879 (1384210970)`

All code compiles without issue deploying and in UI with Compile link on Apex Classes page. All tests pass too.

Any guidance on the core underlying issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't feel the statement "_Stack Exchanging is a viable option for troubleshooting GACKs_" is entirely genuine. That official developer blog article that you linked to says that Salesforce support will be able to see a question here, but that still implies that you're working directly with Salesforce's customer support. I believe that most of the contributors here (myself included) are customers of Salesforce (rather than employees of Salesforce), _and pretty much the only people capable of making use of the GACK error Ids are Salesforce employees._

Comment: Had this happen when a lightning component referenced a property that no longer existed. Only sf can tell you for sure

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit a case to find out more. Most likely, the packaging system missed a dependency that was later found during the upload process, or you've accidentally included an unsupported metadata type in your package. It's rare, but it does happen. One thing you could try besides going through support, is to pull your package to a Force.com IDE or another tool, and try to deploy your entire package to a sandbox, scratch org, or new developer org, and see if it deploys okay. If it complains about any missing dependencies, you'll need to add those to your package and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it's going to help someone, but for me, the cause was strange. I've created deep nested LWC component folders in my project (for better management of code). i.e.

```
force-app > main > default > lwc > cmp1 > lwc > cmp2 > lwc > cmp3 > lwc > cmp4 > lwc > cmp5 > lwc > cmp6 > lwc
```

The last LWC component was the reason for the GACK error. I changed the relationship for `cmp6` from  being a child of `cmp5` to being a sibling of `cmp5` . Hope this helps! cheers.